# Cassandra Says Listening on Port 9042 But Couldn't Connect It

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I've running cassandra on my local machine.

I've starting it `sudo service cassandra start`. And then check logs under `var/log/cassandra/system-log` and it says:

```
INFO  [main] 2019-07-28 13:13:17,226 Server.java:162 - Starting listening for CQL clients on localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (unencrypted)...
INFO  [main] 2019-07-28 13:13:17,270 CassandraDaemon.java:501 - Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it
INFO  [SharedPool-Worker-1] 2019-07-28 13:13:27,133 ApproximateTime.java:44 - Scheduling approximate time-check task with a precision of 10 milliseconds
INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2019-07-28 13:13:27,298 CassandraRoleManager.java:339 - Created default superuser role 'cassandra'
```

Then I try to connect with `cqlsh` in terminal and it says: 
`Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`

What is wrong? Also I couldn't see 9042 port with `netstat -tulpn` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh

Uncomment

`# JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public name>"`

and change it to

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname==localhost"
```

2. Set listen_address and broadcast_rpc_address to local ip (get ip address from ifconfig).
3. Restart Cassandra.

Comment: Hi, the config looks like localhost : `# ipv4. If there is only one address it will be selected regardless of ipv4/ipv6.
listen_address: localhost
`. Also the same error shown.

Comment: can you paste the output of nodetool status

Comment: Here it is: `WARN  07:31:44 Small commitlog volume detected at /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; setting commitlog_total_space_in_mb to 4947.  You can override this in cassandra.yaml
WARN  07:31:44 Only 12.232GiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
`

Comment: Updated the answer please check

Answer (score 0):

```
cqlsh localhost 9042
```

This would work if you didn't change the cassandra.yml file.

Comment: Hi, I've didn't change. I've tried it but shows the same error `Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'localhost': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`